# How to run tmux cmds in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, node-modules, tmux, shelljs

Is there any way to run `tmux` cmds like `tmux kill-server` and `tmuxinator start rails_servers` through nodejs. I have searched online but not able to find anything useful which can aid me to remove my error.

I was trying this through `shelljs` npm module but it didn't help me.

I am getting this error ;

> `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`
>   `Permission denied (publickey).`

when using these lines of code to run `tmux` cmds with nodejs

```
shell.exec('ssh -t myremotemachineaddress tmux kill-server');
shell.exec('ssh -t myremotemachineaddress tmuxinator start rails_servers');
```

Here, `shell` is variable used for `shelljs` npm module.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.